# IIS 5 session and Asp.Net session

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-5

If we open IIS 5 Manager and right click on virtual directory --> select *Properties* so that new window opens up --> click *Home Directory tab* --> click *Configuration*, so that again new window opens --> and if in this new window we select *Options tab*, we are then presented with *Enable Session state* option.

Since Asp.Net already supports session, I was wondering how do IIS 5 session and Asp.Net session relate to each other?

thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is for classic ASP session state.

They are not compatible.

Comment: By classic Asp session state you mean that IIS session works only with Asp pages, but it doesn't work with Asp.net pages?

Comment: ASP.NET implement its own Session system.